# Remove wordpress embed share icon?

Tags: embed, oembed

I am modifying my embed-content.php. I find the functions here to remove some oembed icons but not the share icon. I do not find a function to remove JUST the share icon on wordpress oembeds. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered here: [Removing WordPress Icon from oembed link footer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/262688/removing-wordpress-icon-from-oembed-link-footer) .

From the answer to that question:

> Here's the code to remove the site icon markup from embeds:
>
> `add_filter('get_site_icon_url','__return_false', 10, 3);`
>
> If you want to remove the entire site-icon + site-title then use this:
>
> `add_filter('embed_site_title_html','__return_false');`
>
> The right thing to do though would be to upload your own site-icon in
>   the WordPress customizer and show-off your branding. Min image size it
>   needs is 512px.

This article might also be helpful: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/embedding-wordpress-oembed/

Comment: None of that addresses only removing the SHARE icon. I want to keep the site title and site icon. I ONLY want to remove the share icon. Thanks! :)